# Thread safety issues with ConcurrentHashMap while inserting

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working on a project in which I have two tables in a different database with different schemas. So that means I have two different connection parameters for those two tables to connect using JDBC-

Let's suppose below is the config.property file-

```
TABLES: table1 table2

#For Table1
table1.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
table1.user: gardener
table1.password: shavel
table1.driver: jdbc-driver

#For Table2
table2.url: jdbc:mysql://otherhost:3306/forest
table2.user: forester
table2.password: axe
table2.driver: jdbc-driver
```

Below method will read the above `config.properties` file and make a `ReadTableConnectionInfo` object for each tables.

```
  private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").split(" "));

    for (String arg : tableNames) {

        ReadTableConnectionInfo ci = new ReadTableConnectionInfo();

        String url = prop.getProperty(arg + ".url");
        String user = prop.getProperty(arg + ".user");
        String password = prop.getProperty(arg + ".password");
        String driver = prop.getProperty(arg + ".driver");

        ci.setUrl(url);
        ci.setUser(user);
        ci.setPassword(password);
        ci.setDriver(driver);

        tableList.put(arg, ci);

    }
}
```

Below is the `ReadTableConnectionInfo class` that will hold all the `table connection info` for a particular table.

```
public class ReadTableConnectionInfo {

    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String password;
    public String driver;
    public String percentage;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

Now I am creating `ExecutorService` for specified number of threads and passing this `tableList` object (that I created by reading the `config.property file`) to constructor of `ReadTask class` -

```
// create thread pool with given size
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    service.submit(new ReadTask(tableList));
}
```

Below is my `ReadTask` class that implements `Runnable interface` in which each thread will make two connections for each table in the starting before doing anything meaningful.

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {

    private Connection[] dbConnection = null;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<ReadTableConnectionInfo, Connection> tableStatement = new ConcurrentHashMap<ReadTableConnectionInfo, Connection>();

    public ReadTask(LinkedHashMap<String, XMPReadTableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
        this.tableLists = tableList;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            int j = 0;
            dbConnection = new Connection[tableList.size()];

            //loop around the map values and make the connection list
            for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableList.values()) {

                dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(ci.getUrl(), ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(), ci.getDriver());
                tableStatement.putIfAbsent(ci, dbConnection[j]);

                j++;
            }

            //do other meaningful thing here
           }
       }
    }
```

In my above try block, I am making `dbConnection array` for storing two different database connections. And then I have a `tableStatement` as ConcurrentHashMap in which I am storing `ReadTableConnectionInfo` object with it's `dbConnection`. For example Table1 object will have Table1 connection in the `tableStatement` ConcurrentHashMap.

**Problem Statement:-**

I am trying to see whether is there any potential `thread safety issues` here in my run method with the way I am inserting in `tableStatement` ConcurrentHashMap or any other thread safety issues here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're task classes are not shared between threads (in your current example), and as such there are no concurrency issues in accessing the objects internal state. Currently, each instance of your task is only accessed in the thread it is assigned to by the executor:

```
service.submit(new ReadTask(tableList));
```

With the above line of code, you instantiate an instance of `ReadTask` and ask the executor to run it in a separate thread. If you do not access the object in any other thread then you do not have a concurrency issue.

In your example, actually, you do not need to use a concurrent hash map (as you are not providing any means for external objects to modify that collection).

If you want to do anything to modify your code, consider making the `ReadTableConnectionInfo` object immutable. You can do this by:

- Declaring each of the classes instance variables as final.
- Providing a constructor that accepts values for each one of the instance variables
- Removing the classes `setter` methods
- Using the new constructor in your `readPropertyFile` method.

Comment: Thanks Perception for the suggestion. I have modified my `ReadTask class` slightly just to make it more clear. I won't be modifying `ReadTableConnectionInfo` class in any thread, just I will be doing `getXxx calls`. And can you please explain me what do you mean by `task classes are not shared between threads` as you mentioned in your first line? And why I won't be needing `ConcurrentHashMap`? Because I need to put the data in Map right? so If I am using put with HashMap then it might be possible other thread can messed it right?

Comment: @Nevzz03 - you are submitting a new `ReadTask`'s to your executor. In your ***current*** code, they are not shared between threads. I suppose if you were accessing them in the main thread concurrently then you would need to be more worried about synchronization issues, but in the code you show this is not happening.

Comment: hmmm. I got some part but I didn't got this one- `I suppose if you were accessing them in the main thread concurrently`. Can you provide an example for this, just to make myself more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Nevzz03 - that was more of a general purpose statement, you don't have to worry about it too much, since you don't actually provide any way to change the internal state of your task class.